# Getting the maximum value of the tcbbreakpart of a long broken tcolorbox

Tags: counters, tcolorbox

A very long `tcolorbox` can be broken into many boxes. "The parts of the break sequence are numbered by the counter tcbbreakpart." (p. 363 of manual 4.11)

Is there a way to get the maximum value of `tcbbreakpart` and replace "X" with it ?

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

% Example modified from  tcolorbox-example.tex (2017-09-14) by Prof. Dr. Dr. Thomas F. Sturm

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,breakable,pad at break*=1mm,
colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black,title={Example modified from  tcolorbox-example.tex (2017-09-14) by Prof. Dr. Dr. Thomas F. Sturm},
fonttitle=\huge\bfseries,
title after break={\huge\bfseries
This is p. \arabic{tcbbreakpart} of a total of X pages for this long  broken TColorBox},
watermark color=yellow,watermark text=\Roman{tcbbreakpart}]
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use the `\label` and `reference` system, extracting the stored `tcbbreakpart` number for a particular box.

The `\postboxlabel` macro adds a fake label with the `tcbbreakpart` value *after* the box has been typeset.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{refcount}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\postboxlabel}[1]{\protected@edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@tcbbreakpart\endcsname\thetcbbreakpart}\label{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% Example modified from  tcolorbox-example.tex (2017-09-14) by Prof. Dr. Dr. Thomas F. Sturm

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,breakable,pad at break*=1mm,
colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black,title={Example modified from  tcolorbox-example.tex (2017-09-14) by Prof. Dr. Dr. Thomas F. Sturm},
fonttitle=\huge\bfseries,
title after break={\huge\bfseries
This is p. \arabic{tcbbreakpart} of a total of \getrefnumber{mynicebox} pages for this long  broken TColorBox},
watermark color=yellow,watermark text=\Roman{tcbbreakpart},after={\postboxlabel{mynicebox}}]
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{tcolorbox}


\end{document}
```

[image]